# How to extend reference many field with custom sorting, filtering and actions

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

Have anyone extended the reference many field functionality with custom sorting, filtering and actions. Using built in grid or something like "React Grid".

Would be awesome with some examples.

Edit: I started on my own reference many controller tailored to be used together with dev extreme react grid. Got displaying of data and sorting in place but can't filtering to work. This is what i have so far. As you can see mostly a copy of reference many controller.

I tried putting the filters in the state of controller as that works for paging, but doing that caused the component to go into infinite recursion. I'm guessing i need to dispatch an action so that the filter state resides in redux state.

Any help i welcome.

```
import { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { crudGetManyReference as crudGetManyReferenceAction } from "react-admin";
import { getIds, getReferences, nameRelatedTo } from "react-admin";

    export class Controller extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          sort: props.sort
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchReferences();
      }

      componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.record.id !== nextProps.record.id) {
          this.fetchReferences(nextProps);
        }
      }

      setSort = (field, order) => {
        this.setState({ sort: { field, order } }, this.fetchReferences);
      };

      setFilter = filter => {
        // How to do this?
        // The filters coming in is correct format as object with keys and 
        // values. 
        console.log(filter);
      };

      fetchReferences(
        { reference, record, resource, target, perPage, source, filter } = this
          .props
      ) {
        const { crudGetManyReference } = this.props;
        const pagination = { page: 1, perPage };
        const relatedTo = nameRelatedTo(
          reference,
          record[source],
          resource,
          target,
          filter
        );
        crudGetManyReference(
          reference,
          target,
          record[source],
          relatedTo,
          pagination,
          this.state.sort,
          filter
        );
      }

      render() {
        const { resource, reference, data, ids, children, basePath, filter } = this.props;
        const referenceBasePath = basePath.replace(resource, reference);
        return children({
          currentSort: this.state.sort,
          currentFilter: filter,
          data,
          ids,
          isLoading: typeof ids === "undefined",
          referenceBasePath,
          setSort: this.setSort,
          setFilter: this.setFilter
        });
      }
    }

    Controller.propTypes = {
      basePath: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      children: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      crudGetManyReference: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      filter: PropTypes.object,
      ids: PropTypes.array,
      perPage: PropTypes.number,
      record: PropTypes.object,
      reference: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      data: PropTypes.object,
      resource: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      sort: PropTypes.shape({
        field: PropTypes.string,
        order: PropTypes.oneOf(["ASC", "DESC"])
      }),
      source: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      target: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      isLoading: PropTypes.bool
    };

    Controller.defaultProps = {
      filter: {},
      perPage: 25,
      sort: { field: "id", order: "DESC" },
      source: "id"
    };

    function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
      const relatedTo = nameRelatedTo(
        props.reference,
        props.record[props.source],
        props.resource,
        props.target,
        props.filter
      );
      return {
        data: getReferences(state, props.reference, relatedTo),
        ids: getIds(state, relatedTo)
      };
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
      crudGetManyReference: crudGetManyReferenceAction
    })(Controller);
```